# How to convert a variable to boolean in AutoHotkey?

Tags: type-conversion, boolean, autohotkey, boolean-operations, coercion

In JavaScript, we could do the following:

```js
!!0 // false
Boolean(1) // true
```

How to achieve this in AutoHotkey? For example, convert `WinExist("ahk_exe foo.exe")` to a boolean value and print it out using `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "boolean" type in AHK.  "false" and "true" are just macros that evaluate to 0 and 1.  So, `!!0` is the same as `0`.  You should be able to print the results of `WinExist` in `MsgBox` directly.

If you really do want to convert an arbitrary integer to 0/1, you can use `not not x` or `x != 0`.